# C++ Hexadecimal notation and bitwise operators performance

Tags: c++, optimization, bitwise-operators

Probably a stupid question, but I have a C++ application in which I often do:

```
x & 0xff
```

Where x is a 32-bit integer. Is there any performance benefit in putting the leading zeroes in as well, so it's an AND operation between two 32-bit numbers?

```
x & 0x000000ff
```

I read that any operands smaller than int will be promoted to int before the operation is evaluated. I guess this is an optimization compilers do automatically, or am I helping MSVC in any way by putting those leading zeroes there?

Comment: I am pretty sure any compiler will optimize that, but you can always check the generated assembly code to see it for yourself.

Comment: The CPU will zero extend even if the compiler emits a byte move into the register. The compiler shouldn't bother keeping the leading zeros.

Comment: both `0x000000ff` and `0xff` are `int` literals, so no difference in type and performance. `0x000000ff may affect compiler performance by a few nanoseconds or something like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding those zeros to your source code makes absolutely no difference. They're removed in the lexing phase, before the compiler has even finished parsing the code. They cannot affect code generation.

Answer (score 1):

Write this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 400;
#ifdef SHORT
    std::cout << (x & 0xFF) << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << (x & 0x000000FF) << std::endl;
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with and without -DSHORT:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -DSHORT main.cpp -o test_short

g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o test_long
```

Diff the executables generated, they are exactly the same (tested with and without -O3 option).

So the g++ compiler handles this correctly and you don't need to take care of that when writting your code (adding zeros having absolutely no impact on the generated code). I don't have MSVC, but you can do exactly the same test and check if outputs are different!

Comment: Note: the OP is not using `g++`.

Comment: @owacoder: True, I missed that: he can repeat the same test with any compiler....;-)

Comment: It's like checking whether `73 * 137` still equals 10001 today as it did yesterday - any doubt here is counter-productive

Comment: @anatolyg: I don't undertsand your comment. Having the same exacutable definitely means that adding zeros in the code is absolutely pointless...no?